# laravel where raw automaticaly add is null

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

i have this code where i need to join transactions with transaction_sell_lines and transactions with purchase_lines. Then purchase_lines and transaction_sell_lines both has variation_id. I need to join those variation_id to variations table.

```
 Transaction::leftJoin('purchase_lines as pl', 'transactions.id', '=', 'pl.transaction_id')
 ->leftJoin('transaction_sell_lines as sl', 'transactions.id', '=', 'sl.transaction_id')
 ->join('variations as v', function ($query) {
     $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(COALESCE(sl.variation_id, ''), COALESCE(pl.variation_id, ''))"));
 }, '=', 'v.id')
```

and when i checked the query using `DB::enableQueryLog();` for some reason laravel automatically add is null even though i did not mention it anywhere. i could use `whereNotNull()` but the result still are not the same. the code could be seen below

```
from `transactions` left join `purchase_lines` as `pl` on `transactions`.`id` = `pl`.`transaction_id` 
left join `transaction_sell_lines` as `sl` on `transactions`.`id` = `sl`.`transaction_id` 
inner join `variations` as `v` on CONCAT(COALESCE(sl.variation_id, ''), COALESCE(pl.variation_id, '')) is null
```

how do i achieve this sql

```
from transactions LEFT JOIN purchase_lines as pl on pl.transaction_id = transactions.id 
LEFT JOIN transaction_sell_lines as sl ON sl.transaction_id = transactions.id
LEFT JOIN variations as v on v.id = CONCAT(COALESCE(sl.variation_id,''),COALESCE(pl.variation_id,''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you replace

```
$query->where(DB::raw("...")
```

with the `whereRaw`-function instead:

```
 Transaction::leftJoin('purchase_lines as pl', 'transactions.id', '=', 'pl.transaction_id')
 ->leftJoin('transaction_sell_lines as sl', 'transactions.id', '=', 'sl.transaction_id')
 ->join('variations as v', function ($query) {
     $query->whereRaw("CONCAT(COALESCE(sl.variation_id, ''), COALESCE(pl.variation_id, ''))");
 }, '=', 'v.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using [Advanced Join Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses) the wrong way ...

join with  closure should take a Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause instance which allows you to specify constraints on the "join" clause, so the constraints should be in that function:

you can replace:

```
 ->join('variations as v', function ($query) {
     $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(COALESCE(sl.variation_id, ''), COALESCE(pl.variation_id, ''))"));
 }, '=', 'v.id')
```

with:

```
 ->join('variations as v', function ($query) {
     $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(COALESCE(sl.variation_id, ''), COALESCE(pl.variation_id, ''))=v.id"));
 })
```